# Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack git://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php

Tags: git, heroku, buildpack

I would like to push a new app to Heroku using `git push heroku master`.

After successful authentication have got following error.

> remote: Building source: remote: remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack
>     git://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php... done remote:
>
> remote:  !Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack
>     git://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php

`detect` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "$1/composer.lock" ]; then
    echo "PHP (composer.json)" && exit 0
elif [ -f "$1/index.php" ]; then
    echo "PHP (classic)" && exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This buildback is deprecated, you should use official `Heroku` buildpack instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to check the `detect` file in the buildpack for the requirements it is checking against. Any condition that causes it to exit 1 will cause Heroku to report a push rejection.

Comment: Assuming,  you have `composer.lock` and `index.php` in the project root directory (make sure), check if the project folder structure is correctly presented to heroku when you push i.e. not having the app root buried in a subfolder. Buildpacks for a particular language/framework expect to find the necessary files in the root to consider it a valid app.  For example in a `node` app, every buildpack looks for a `package.json` in the root.

Comment: I have cloned this project, so I haven't `index.php` in project root only `composer.lock`.

Comment: Given the elif condition you should be find with having either one of the files.

Comment: So isn't causes this the problem?

Comment: Your logs don't show any messages from the compile script so I would make sure the folder structure is correct first.

Comment: I have copied also `index.php` in root folder, but same error again. Nothing changed.

Comment: I took a look at the buildpack, If there are no more log messages, something like `Bundling NGINX ${NGINX_VERSION}` then it is failing on the detect script because the compile scripts have a few log messages it should print out .  If you have other error messages, show them here. If you are willing, fork the buildpack repo and put in some log messages where it starts the compilation process in the compile script at line [267](https://github.com/CHH/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/compile#L267) and see if it reaching there at all.

Comment: Also here is the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) on the error message. "This situation may also occur if you remove or rename a file that previously led to the automatic detection of your application type and thus the automatic setting of the detected buildpack on your application."

Comment: It says about a file, but I cannot locate it.
`Script error in /tmp/buildpack20160408-162-rmvmk4/bin/compile on or near line 380`

Comment: This answer is *wrong*.  The `detect` script fails unless it exits with 0: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-detect